# Isolating numbers in folder names

Tags: vbscript

I have created a script, out of snip-its found all over this site and elsewhere, to assign job numbers.  It (is supposed to) search the "Jobs" directory for the highest job number, increment by 1, prompt for a customer name and job name, copy a template dir and rename it with the information provided.  I know my code is messy, but it worked wonderfully...until someone put numbers in the job name (09889KM-TCM-Vadata PDX50 - POD 3).  It now does it's intended job, but then runs again with the next number it finds in the job name i.e. increments 09889 to 09890 then picks up on PDX50 and tries to make a new folder 00051.  I have been looking all day to find how to isolate the numbers on my own and, but as this script is in production I have no choice to beg for help.  Please assist on how to isolate the first 5 digits, or make it stop after one run.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO
Dim objNewFolder
Dim fs
Dim MainFolder
DIM JobNumber, nJobNumber, EmplInit, CustName, JobName
Dim fldr, LastName, LastJob, r, x, y
Dim OldFolder, sFile

'Find Highest Job Number Folder
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MainFolder = fs.GetFolder("C:\Test\")
For Each fldr In MainFolder.SubFolders
        If fldr.Name > LastName Then
        LastJob = fldr.Name
        LastName = fldr.Name
    End If
Next


'Extract JobNumber from name and increment by 1, and format to five numbers
Set r=new regexp
r.pattern="[0-9]+"
r.global=true
x=LastJob
Set y=r.execute(x)
For each JobNumber in y
    JobNumber = Right("00000" & JobNumber, 5)
    nJobNumber = JobNumber + 1
    nJobNumber = Right("00000" & nJobNumber, 5)

' Start recieving input
' Get initials
EmplInit = InputBox ("The last Job Number is: " & VbCrLf & Jobnumber & VbCrLf & "You have been assigned Job Number: " & VbCrLf & nJobNumber & VbCrLf & "Please Typer your initials:","Initials")
    If IsEmpty(EmplInit) Then
        MsgBox "Canceled"
    ElseIf Len(EmplInit) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You Clicked OK but left the box blank"
Else

 'Get Customer Name
 CustName = InputBox ("Please enter your customer's name:","Customer Name")
    If IsEmpty(EmplInit) Then
        MsgBox "Canceled"
    ElseIf Len(EmplInit) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You Clicked OK but left the box blank"
 Else

  'Get Job Name
 JobName = InputBox ("Please enter your job's name:","Job Name")
    If IsEmpty(EmplInit) Then
        MsgBox "Canceled"
    ElseIf Len(EmplInit) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You Clicked OK but left the box blank"
 Else
 ' Create New Job Folder Name
 objNewFolder = ("C:\Test\" & nJobNumber & EmplInit & "-" & CustName & "-" & JobName)


'Create the File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder we want to copy from
OldFolder = "C:\Test\00AA-Working Edit - Folder Template\"
'Check if new folder exists, if not then create it.
If objFSO.FolderExists (objNewFolder) then
    WScript.Echo "The Destination Folder " & objNewFolder & " already exists"
    Else
    WScript.Echo "The Destination Folder " & objNewFolder & " will be created."
    Set objNewFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder (objNewFolder)
    End If

'Copy source folders to new folder
objFSO.CopyFolder "C:\Test\00AA-Working Edit - Folder Template\*" , (objNewFolder & "\")
'Copy any files in the source root to new location

For Each sFile In objFSO.GetFolder(OldFolder).Files
    If Not objFSO.FileExists(objNewFolder & "\" & objFSO.GetFileName(sFile)) Then
        objFSO.GetFile(sFile).Copy objNewFolder & "\" & objFSO.GetFileName(sFile),True

    End If
 Next

End If
End If
End If


Next
```

Comment: You can escape the outer `For...Next` loop just before you enter the last Next by an `Exit For` statement. That would be the fastest way with minimal risk of unwanted side effects. If you want to have it clean, you can `Regex.Test` it and if it evaluates to `True`, you can get the first item instead of looping over all items by `JobNumber = y.item(0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
'Extract JobNumber from name and increment by 1, and format to five numbers
Set r=new regexp
r.pattern="[0-9]+"
r.global=true
x=LastJob
```

To this:

```
'Extract JobNumber from name and increment by 1, and format to five numbers
Set r=new regexp
r.pattern="[0-9]+"
r.global=true
x=Left(LastJob,5)
```

You're just changing one line (the last).

Comment: Thank you Everyone!  I have implemented Nathan's answer and that has fixed the problem.  I am going to go through all answers and see how each one works.  I appreciate the community, this site and all it's members have been a great outlet for learning VBS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the regular expression. In fact, it sounds like that's part of your problem because in addition to finding the first 5 digits, it's finding any digits *within* the folder name and operating on those as well.

After you determine `LastJob`, just do this:

```
x = Left(LastJob, 5)

If IsNumeric(x) Then

    nJobNumber = Right("00000" & x + 1, 5)

    ' Start your InputBox() prompts...

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r.pattern="^[0-9]+"
```

To avoid more changes in code, just indicate in the regexp that the pattern should be at the start of line.